# Assign approval role to site collection administrator in Nintex workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

we are using Nintex 2013 workflow in sharepoint 2013 environment for approval process. At present only the pre-assigned approvers can complete(Approve or Reject) the task. Now we have the scionario if actual approver is on leave, then the site collection administrator should be able to compelete the task(Approve or Reject). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How do you propose to let the workflow know if the approver is on leave?? I would suggest using a parallel approval task that allows more than one person to approve, and end the workflow on first approval.

For a Nintex-centric approach I would suggest consulting their support team directly. They're very responsive and this is one of the reasons the product costs so much.